# Adb shell sysdump consuming too much CPU on device

Tags: android, adb, profiling

I have made an android profiler which keeps pinging the device using adb shell commands for memory usage, frames and battery stats, the profiler works fine but what i noticed is the adb shell commands which are executed every 16ms (sampling rate) itself contribute to high CPU usage on the device and the app im profiling becomes laggy. Is this expected behaviour where adb commands are CPU intensive since its an entire system dump.

PS: Im trying to do android profiling in a CI CD, and want to profile an app in release build, so the default Android Studio profilers wont be applicable here.

Comment: If you want to know what commands Android Studio uses for profiling you can try to capture the ADB USB traffic e.g. using Wireshark.

Comment: Sure that sounds like a good start.. Will try it out.. Thanks :)